# When is meromorphic continuation possible?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analyticity

Suppose I have an expression of the form

$$f(z) := f_1(z)+f_2(z)$$
($f,f_1,f_2$ can e.g. be integrals)
with $f_1$ convergent in the region $R_1=\{\Re(z)>-1\}$ and $f_2$ convergent in the region $R_2=\{\Re(z)<1\}$.

Let $R= R_1\cap R_2$. 
Then, to my knowledge, $f$ is convergent in $R$. My question is when is it possible to meromorphically extend $f$ to a larger region, say all of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You have a continuation across $\Re z = -1$ if and only if $f_1$ has one, and a continuation across $\Re z = 1$ if and only if $f_2$ has one.

Comment: Makes sense, I suspected this. Thanks for the answer.